# Configure Mail in Liberty server

Tags: jakarta-mail, websphere-liberty

We are migrating our application code from WAS 8.0 to Liberty 17.0.0.1. Our application uses mail functionality which gets invoked when user process a request. Could anyone help us in configuring mail in server.xml. Whether it is mandatory to provide user and password for  tag in server.xml ?

Comment: You can find the `<mailSession>` and all server.xml config documentation here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.liberty.autogen.core.doc/ae/rwlp_config_mailSession.html

Answer (score 2):

I *just* did this myself. The XML requires you to provide those attributes, but if your server(s) don't require authentication, you can leave them blank.

e.g. here's mine (with server values changed, of course), where I currently only need to send outgoing mail via SMTP, which is the default for the optional [`transportProtocol`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.liberty.autogen.nd.doc/ae/rwlp_config_mailSession.html) attribute:

```xml
<mailSession description="My mail server" from="" host="mymailserver.com"
             id="myMail" jndiName="mail/myMail" mailSessionID="myMailSession" 
             password="" user=""/>
```

Comment: Hi we had configured the same in our server.xml but we are getting the below error "SMTP server 'Message Send Failurecom.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: MFTest.metlife.com, 25; timeout -1;--nested exception is:--java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)"

Comment: That's purely a networking issue. Either the server or port are incorrect, or your network/routing/firewalls need changes to allow the connection.

Comment: Hi dbreaux, the server and port details were correct. We had double verified that. We tried to add property for timeout. But that also doesn't work. Firewall connection has also been changed

Comment: That exception clearly means it can't connect. Can you test on the command-line? https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/Dougclectica/entry/testing_remote_tcp_ip_connectivity

Comment: Got the below one when I tried to test the connectivity from my Application Sever  Command - "ssh MFTest.metlife.com -p 25" Response - "connect to host MFTest.metlife.com port 25: Connection timed out"

Comment: Right, so that means it's a network/system connectivity issue, not a Liberty/Java one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are configuring the mail session in the server.xml then the userid and password are required. You have the option of encoding the password with the securityUtility (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSRTLW_9.0.1/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rwlp_command_securityutil.html) provided with Liberty.